# msi uninstall problem not removing a file

Tags: wix

I have a wix project which creates an msi.  One problem that I am finding is that when I uninstall the service the .exe.config file is left behind.  All other files are removed.

The files are installed in exactly the same way, the only difference being that the .exe.config has a custom action applied to it to edit the file.

Is there something that I need to do specially to make sure the file gets removed on uninstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you edit the file and change its modified time, the Windows Installer will think it is a "user file" and not remove it. A Windows Installer log file should show you this. The easiest solution is to not modify the modified time (or reset the modified time back to the created time) when editing the file.